# Would it not be helpful to have an FAQ page or location where common links can be found?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Perhaps it's my inexperience with the stack model, but I find it exceptionally difficult in many cases to find a link to a common issue. Often it makes more sense to link to some discussion or question rather than explaining a whole mess of things.

One example would be my comment here:

[Critique: Modified template for a greeting card service](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30824/critique-modified-template-for-a-greeting-card-service) 
<sub>*Well not now :) comments have been purged on that question apparently :)*</sub>

To find a link to the critique guidelines I have to search meta. Which was okay for this particular use, but often when searching there can be a whole list of similar but unrelated items if you aren't familiar with the ***exact*** post wording.

Example: https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1085/what-dpi-ppi-for-print-initiative-on-gd (Didn't need to delete this Yisela :).. it was a prime example of why this is needed, not a commentary on the post directly. )

**I can't find a FAQ link anywhere.** I think the help center revamp wiped it out. Or am I missing it?

I don't know how to access the "Community Wiki". I don't think I've **ever** seen a link to that. Or I've missed it for, literally, years. I see the wiki posts... but no wiki "roll" as it were.

There are a number of common questions/meta posts which should be easy to find... Critique Guidelines, Font ID guidelines, Stock image resources, type resources, to name a few.

Would it make sense to have a common area where these informational posts are all located to try and separate them from the general Q&A? Not entirely, but more of a predetermined search parameter.

I think what's really needed may be:

- A) a link to view the Community Wiki as an actual Wiki (bottom of Community Bulletin sidebar perhaps?).
- B) Some moderator-only ability to designate a question/meta post as
  "common information" or "FAQ" then a link to view only those
  designated questions/posts.

Comment: This would be AMAZING, some way of using snippets in-site. I can't tell how many times I have written the same message, with slight variations, and how much time I've spent looking for questions I kiiiind of remember are similar. Where there is a need there could be a feature, 100% for this.

Comment: This is definitely the most glaring UX problem with SE generally. When experienced users are perplexed, what chance do the noobs have?

Comment: Hell yes. I suggest that for now we MacGyver something together as a stopgap using meta posts and a tag like `guidelines`, and also drop a proper feature request to meta.meta. Maybe have a master post that describes the series and links to and is linked from them all, that is permanently "featured".

Comment: Excellent idea @user568458 http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1087/what-are-the-guidelines-for-specific-questions/1088#1088

Comment: Not an answer, but a stopgap: You can find all Community Wiki posts by searching with `wiki:1` (and add `is:q` if you want only questions in your results list).

Comment: The [tag:faq] tag still exists on Meta, too. Not really sure what you're asking for here.

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller Just a standard FAQ. One document, one link, where all the common answers are posted. The FAQ in the help section is both scant and generic. I've never known where to begin looking for critique guidelines. *Why* can't this be nicely organized?

Comment: @LaurenIpsum By "the help section" I take it you're looking at the URL http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help. It sounds like you want it to be replaced or augmented by a single page that lists site-specific information, for example [What are the guidelines for asking for a critique of my work?](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work), rather than what it has now, which is mostly the same for every site in the network. Is that right?

Comment: @Pops YES, exactly. So an actual list of the Questions which are Frequently Asked on GDSE (and the answers), not just boilerplate SE guidelines which barely apply here.

Comment: I don't think a FAQ needs to replace anything. I feel it should be a site-specific link. While the "Help Center" refers to how the Stack model works, the FAQ would refer to how GD.SE works. Both are needed. And I imagine every single Stack site would benefit from something similar.

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller but the FAQ tag results in.... a blank page. And it's a moderator-only tag :) Which is fine, if it were used, that may help considerably. :)

Comment: Basically, I envision a "FAQ" link which when clicked, it brings up something similar to [this meta answer](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1087/are-there-guidelines-for-specific-question-types-or-references-to-review-before/1088#1088). The primary difference being that rather than needing to copy/paste questions into an answer, a moderator can simply flag (or tag) them as FAQ content and that question/post gets added to the page. Honestly, if Mods add the FAQ tag to these types of thing it would be very similar. But can you add FAQ tags to the main site?

Comment: One big issue is actually accessing the Community Wiki. I admit I didn't do a great deal of research on that, but I didn't have any clue how to get to it until I read Abby's comment above.

Comment: Apparently the FAQ link is only blank when accessed from Abby's link above because it refers to the main site (again, can FAQ tags be added there?) Actually adding the tag as a favorite on meta, then clicking it does bring up 5 meta posts. Some of which aren't really faq but refer to editing the faq (which is gone), others are exceptionally good information to share with users of all experience levels. But how many new users are going to search for the FAQ tag? That's my general point. I feel it needs to be a UI item

Comment: @Pops: the Meta Answer which Scott linked to above? THAT'S effectively what I want. But in the menu. Somewhere easily accessible.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**: I think you can achieve your goals by using existing functionality.

To be frank, I don't understand your first request at all. I think of "Community Wiki" as a *status* that can be applied to individual posts, not a single monolithic entity that can be linked to.

Historically, CW has never quite served the purpose it was designed for. Heck, ask five long-time SE users what its purpose is, and you'll get seven different answers. Views on CW [have been changing](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) for about as long as the network has been around, and they're still evolving [as of two weeks ago](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/).

(I must admit I don't spend much time on GD SE specifically, so if you have a local convention I'm unaware of, I apologize. I did a quick search and didn't see any obvious differences from what I'm used to or a clear unifying theme.)

As for your second request, moderators already have a superpower for creating FAQ entries. Only mods may apply the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag to posts on Meta GD SE. If the number of site-specific rules you have is limited, you might be able to get away with posting each one as an answer to a single "official FAQ question." A more robust solution is to give each site rule its own [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)-tagged question — after community discussion, of course — and maintain a central "directory" page [like Meta Stack Exchange does](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Also, the site's mods can already edit [the "What topics can I ask about here?" page](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) within the help center. It's not *exactly* what you're looking for, but I think it's similar enough to deserve a mention.

The use case that I haven't covered yet is questions frequently asked **on the main site**. Traditionally, other network sites have handled this situation by selecting one question to be "the canonical one" and closing new questions on the topic as duplicates of that canonical one. Another approach is to use tag wikis to link to common questions about those tags, [like the Scala folks did on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info). I think it would be fine to maintain a master list as a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)-tagged question here on meta, too.

Comment: Good stuff. I guess my Interpretation of the CW was yet another vision :) - Wasn't aware mods could edit "What topics" area. That would help. As would adding the FAQ tag where appropriate (and removing it where not). Ultimately it sounds like it's more a localized organizational issue than a feature issue.